# ColdFusion 11 is missing the X-REWRITE-URL CGI header when using the GetHttpRequestData function

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We have been using the `GetHttpRequestData().headers["X-REWRITE-URL"]` variable for our SEO optimized websites. Now we have upgraded the website to ColdFusion 11 and we can no longer access our SEO URI from the ColdFusion request headers.

Is there any other way to read this variable?

Comment: The `X-REWRITE-URL` header is only available when using a rewrite module. Is that still in place?